# Showing a response in a div

Tags: jquery

I currently have the `resp` showing in an alert.

How can I show it in my `span` with the `class` error?

**Code:**

```
if(resp == '')
        {

        }else{
            alert(resp);
        }
    },
```

Comment: Try this $('.error').text(resp);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(resp == '')
        {

        }else{
                                //!!!! set your response --                                     
           $("span.error").html(resp);
//here select span ^^^^ with class error
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(resp != null && resp != ''){
    var span = document.createElement('span ');
    span .className = 'error';
    span .innerHTML = resp ;
    document.getElementById('parentDivId').appendChild(span);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
if(resp == '')
{//some code.
}else{
    $(".error").text(resp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(resp == '')
        {
           // Do whatever your want
        }else{
            $('.errorspan').text(resp);
        }
    }
```